# Too many values to unpack — delimiters and file input output

Tags: python

On the following line of text I get the following error ('too many values to unpack') and I'm not sure why:

```
MATH 1426,preprofessional,MATH 1323,
```

For that line of data, I have:

```
course, category, pre, = split("\W+", line)
```

Why do I keep on getting that error. Even when I add a fourth variable it still says it.  The ("W+\") function splits the line by non-word character so what am I missing. In my eyes that line is split 3 times so at most I should need 4 variables and even when I use 4, I still get the same error.

Comment: what exactly are you wanting to split the string on? Also, what exactly is the error you are getting? I don't believe that this code makes sense, what is split doing? As this appears to be an improper use of the split function

Comment: i have this split method through several different files. I want to split the course at the comma after course, the comma after category, and the comma after the other class. I have done it several times just to split at commas, semicolons, whatever it may be, however i see in this case i could just split with the comma

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: To split at the commas,

```
string = 'MATH 1426,preprofessional,MATH 1323' # i have left out the final comma for neatness
split_string = string.split(',')
#gives you
['MATH 1426', 'preprofessional', 'MATH 1323']
```

By default the split method splits on white space or you can specify one delimiter like a comma, but you appear to be trying to split on
`'\W+'`, and this doesn't result in any split. It results in:

```
`['MATH 1426,preprofessional,MATH 1323,']`
```

Check out this link for a quick guide to the re modules special symbols, [here](http://python.about.com/od/regularexpressions/a/regexprimer.htm).

Comment: It's `\W` rather than `/W`, and that means 'non-word characters', which means spaces and punctuation.

Comment: Thanks. I mixed it up with \w(lower case) Fixed.